# Usage of ignored PTE bits for x86-64

Tags: linux, windows, operating-system, paging, x86-64

The Intel software manual specifies that in IA-32e paging mode the page table entry contains several ignored bits (specifically, bits 11:9 and bits 62:52, for a total of 14 bits). If I understand correctly, these bits can be set to anything. Does any OS or other system use these bits for storing auxiliary information?

Comment: Are the bits explicitly stated to be **unused**; or are they **reserved** or **undefined**?

Comment: They state these bits to be "ignored", the reserved bits are denoted separately.